# OneDrive Webservice - Can different users access my OneDrive?

Tags: wordpress, web-services, onedrive

i want to implement a REST webservice in my wordpress blog. Visitors or other users can select images from my OneDrive Account and order them.

My problem is when i get the authentication `code` i must enter my password für OneDrive. After that i get the `access_token`. The `access_token` has only a runtime for 1 hour.

When i order i new `access_token` the `code` is expired and i must get a new authentication code with my user password.

How i can implement a webservice for OneDrive without enter my own password everytime?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the `access_token` through the [code flow](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#code-flow) when authing you should also see a `refresh_token` come back (provided you requested the **wl.offline_access** scope). You should be able to use that to get a new `access_token` by using the [this process](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#step-3-get-a-new-access-token-or-refresh-token) without requiring user interaction.